# Keep row names when extracting a data frame from a list of lists

Tags: r

I have a list of lists called cj1. Each list contains multiple data frames/elements. I want to extract the first element/data frame from each list in a separate list of data frames.
The first rows in the first element of each list look like this

```
as.data.frame(cj1[[1]]) 
                    cj1[[1]]
..a15.pdf         1.27679608
..a17.pdf         1.05090176
..a18.pdf         1.51820192
```

..a15.pdf etc. is a rowname. To extract my desired list (results1) I try:

```
results1<-sapply(cj1, function(x) as.data.frame(cj1[[1]]))
```

But this does not preserve the rownames, and I need them:

```
> results1[[1]]
 [1]   1.27679608   1.05090176   1.51820192   2.30296037   1.48568732
```

I tried to convert the rownames into a column before extracting the data frames:

```
cj1<-sapply(cj1, function(x) rownames_to_column(cj1[[1]], var="names"))
```

But this gives an error

```
Error in rownames_to_column(cj1[[1]], var = "names") : 
  is.data.frame(df) is not TRUE
```

So I tried to convert to a data frame:

```
cj1<-sapply(cj1, function(x)as.data.frame(cj1[[1]]))
```

but it also removes row names

```
     cj1[[1]]
1    1.27679608
2    1.05090176
3    1.51820192
```

If it can help to get a solution, the element I am trying to extract is called coefficients. Looks like this:
[image]

EDIT: I've tried a for loop. This preserves the rownames, but apparently all dataframes in my new list are the same. used 462 because my list has 462 lists.

```
#Create an empty list
results1 <- c()
# Create a for statement to populate the list
for (i in 1:462) {
  results1[[i]] <- as.data.frame(cj1[[1]])
}
```

Comment: `[[` extracts a vector. With `[`, you will get a one-column data frame, including the row names. So in your code change `cj1[[1]]` to `cj1[1]`.

Comment: Though I think you have a typo, since you are using an anonymous function of `x`, you might really be wanting `x[1]`, not `cj1[1]`.

Comment: I tried both: results1<-sapply(cj1, function(x) as.data.frame(x[[1]]))
results1<-sapply(cj1, function(x) as.data.frame(x[1])) and they do not work, if that is what you meant by your second comment: Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[1]]) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"name"’ to a data.frame. I tried your first suggestion and this is how it looks: as.data.frame(results1[1])
   c...a15.pdf...1.27679607834331....a17.pdf...1.05090175857491..
1                                                      1.27679608
2                                                      1.05090176

Comment: So with the first suggestion, it still seems that the rownames are converted to 1,2,3.. However you can see a name there as well c...15pdf